# Can the javascript .bind go up multiple levels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

I have a piano Keyboard object in JavaScript and JQuery, like so:

```
function Keyboard(name, size, xPos, yPos, octaves) {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = size;

    this.setDimensions = function (){};

    this.highlightKeyboard = function (){};
    ...
    etc.
}
```

It's got a bunch of methods to set dimensions, generate the keyboard using divs for the keys, generate major and minor scales referencing the classes of the divs, etc.

I wrote 4 methods to highlight a major scale when I press a  certain key, a minor scale when I press a different key, major and minor triads with two other keys. They all worked, but after writing them I realized all 4 methods use a lot of the same code so I've been trying to consolidate by bringing out most of the code into separate methods in the main Keyboard object so I can call them repeatedly.

The problem I'm having now that I'm consolidating is getting the `$(document).keypress` objects to play nice with the external code.

What I want is something like this (partial code sample—I left out all the code to generate the keyboard and everything else that wasn't relevant because it seems to be working OK other than this one issue):

```
function Keyboard(name, size, xPos, yPos, octaves) {

    this.getMajorTonic = (function(userNote) {
        // code to determine myTonic
        return myTonic;
    });

    this.setMajScale = function(myTonic) {
        var scale = [];
        // code to determine scale[];            
        return scale;
    };

    this.setScaleClasses = function(scale) {
        // code to determine scale_classes[]
        return scale_classes;
    };

    this.highlightKeyboard = function (scale, scale_classes){};
        // code to add highlighted classes to my divs based
        // on the values in scale and scale_classes 
    };

    this.findMajorScales = function(userNote);
        var myTonic = this.getMajorTonic(userNote);
        var scale = this.setMajScale(myTonic);
        var scale_classes = this.setScaleClasses(scale);
        var highlightKeyboard = this.highlightKeyboard;

        $(document).keypress(function (event) {        
            if (event.which === 109) {
                highlightKeyboard(scale, scale_classes)    
            }
        });
    };
}

var keys = new Keyboard("piano", 1, 0, 0, 2);
keys.findMajorScales("E");
```

The desired effect is that when I load the page, it generates a blank keyboard, but when I press the "m" key, it highlights the E Major scale using the `this.highlightKeyboard` method. So I want to pass the `this.findMajorScales` method a `this.highlightKeyboard` method with no arguments, and then have the arguments filled in and the method executed when the "m" key is pressed. Most everything works, including the `($document).keypress` object—it executes other code, just not the `this.highlightKeyboard` method with the right arguments.

How do I accomplish this? Does .bind have something to do with it? I can't really figure out if it's applicable here or if I need to do something else.

Thanks so much!

Jake

Comment: It looks like you have a _SyntaxError_ on the line beginning `this.highlightKeyboard`; you immediately close the _function_ but continue like it's still open. This may be a copy-paste error. You have another _SyntaxError_ shortly after where you use a delimiter `;` before closing parenthesis for your listener.

Comment: Ack, I always get that `});` part wrong. Thanks. That said, this was retyped, with a lot of stuff left out because the original code is 800 lines, so the syntax errors are only on this page...as far as I know. All the code in `this.highlightKeyboard` used to be inside the `$(document).keypress)` object; I didn't list the code on this page because I know it works within the `$(document).keypress)` object—just not when I try to bring it outside the `this.findMajorScales` method. Would it help if I just linked to the original code?

Comment: Yes, link to the original code if its ok with you.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. S. gave me the solution I needed. Appreciate the response though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I want to pass the this.findMajorScales method a this.highlightKeyboard method with no arguments, and then have the arguments filled in and the method executed when the "m" key is pressed.

You are listening for <kbd>M</kbd> fine, so the only problem you have is invoking `highlightKeyboard` in the correct context.

Consider

```
var foo = {bar: function () {return this}),
    bar = foo.bar;
```

What will `foo.bar()` return? (`foo`)
What will `bar()` return? (`window` or `null` or throws an error, etc)

---

### You have a lot of options

There are several ways around this, you've already mentioned [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and it may be conceptually easier for you to use [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or even passing the `this` variable through using another identifier instead.

In either case, the default `this` in the handler will no longer be an instanceof *Keyboard* as the event is coming from `document`

Using `Function.prototype.bind` you have a few options

```
var highlightKeyboard = this.highlightKeyboard.bind(this);
$(document).keypress(function (event) {        
    if (event.which === 109) {
        highlightKeyboard(scale, scale_classes);
    }
});

// or binding args ahead of time too

var highlightKeyboard = this.highlightKeyboard.bind(this, scale, scale_classes);
$(document).keypress(function (event) {        
    if (event.which === 109) {
        highlightKeyboard();
    }
});

// or binding the handler

$(document).keypress(function (event) {        
    if (event.which === 109) {
        this.highlightKeyboard(scale, scale_classes);
    }
}.bind(this));
```

Using `Function.prototype.call` or `.apply`, requires ref to `this`

```
var highlightKeyboard = this.highlightKeyboard;
var me = this;

$(document).keypress(function (event) {        
    if (event.which === 109) {
        highlightKeyboard.call(me, scale, scale_classes);
    }
});
```

Just using a ref to `this`

```
var me = this;

$(document).keypress(function (event) {        
    if (event.which === 109) {
        me.highlightKeyboard(scale, scale_classes);
    }
});
```

---

Finally, one more solution is to write a function which generates what you want, this is very similar to what `.bind` is doing but is supported in environments that don't support `.bind` (read: legacy)

```
$(document).keypress(function (me) { // this function generates the inside one
    return function (event) { // this is the function used as the handler
        if (event.which === 109) {
            me.highlightKeyboard(scale, scale_classes);
        }
    };
}(this)); // passing in `this` as param `me`
```

Comment: Thanks, that is fantastic help!! I used this first option, but I'm going to try out the others for experience. Very much appreciated!!!!

Comment: This helped me get rid of a few hundred lines of code! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There's no method named `highlightScales` in the Keyboard object. I think you meant `this.highlightKeyboard`.

That being said - `bind()` is used to pass a context to  a method. It allows you to set `this` manually instead of using whatever `this` would be in that scope.

Comment: `.bind` in _jQuery_ is similar to `.on` and different to the _bind_ in _vanilla JavaScript_ that you describe here. The OP isn't very clear on which they mean, though.

Comment: Definitely meant `highlightKeyboard`, thanks! caught it a bit too late though :-)

`highlightScales` is not in my original code though, just what I typed in here.

I did not know that `.bind` was different in jQuery and JavaScript! Thank you. I meant the JavaScript version, I believe.